# Returning function in one line

Tags: python, function, return

> Fill in the box with python code that will make the program behavior
>   match the comments. You may not make any other changes to the code or
>   add code outside the parenthesis " (   )" .
>
> ```
> def bypass_line(age, has_acces_card):
> ''' (int, bool) -> bool
> Return True if and only if the person's age is greater than 50 or
> they have a access card as indicated by has_access_card.
> '''
>
>
> return (                    )
> ```

This is a practice question I am doing. And I am in a dilemma, I know how to write the code...

which is:

```
def bypass_line(age, has_vip):
    if age >70 or has_vip =="yes":
        return True
    return False
```

but how do I write one line of code in the () so that I have answered the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` expression **already** results in a boolean value; it is either `True` or `False`. You can return it directly:

```
return age > 70 or has_vip == "yes"
```

This is essentially what `if` tests for; take your expression, pass it to `bool()` and see if it is either `True` or `False`. The `bool()` is not needed here as comparison operators (`>`  and `==`) themselves already return `True` or `False`:

```
>>> age = 60
>>> age > 70
False
>>> age = 80
>>> age > 70
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
def bypass_line(age, has_acces_card):
    return age > 50 or has_acces_card == "yes"
```

This is basically returning the expression itself that is evaluated by the if-statement.  Since the expression already returns either `True` or `False` in the if-statement, it will do the same here.

Comment: really ?!? I could do that?

Comment: @user2891763: You can return the result of any expression. If the expression *itself* is already `True` or `False`, then just return that directly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your bypass_line function, you can simple write

```
return age > 50 or has_acces_card == "yes"
```

As I'm more of a C++ person, I prefer to organize the code like this. It helps me think more clearly.

```
return (age > 50) or (has_acces_card == "yes")
```

Either way, the code simply checks if the person either

- age is greater than 50
- has an access card

If **either** are true (hence the `or`), the function will return a `True`. Otherwise, it'll return a false.

The logic is exactly the same as in an `if` statement, it's just that the resulting `True` or `False` is used in the `return` statement instead (You still have the same expression, just the result is being used elsewhere). You can use that (or really any) expression anywhere, for example in a `print`, a definition of a variable, as an argument to a function... The logic is always the same.